# Insert or Delete column if does not equal heading

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-2010

I have column headings starting in Column L going forward. The column headings need to be in a certain order.

By hand, I have to insert columns so everything is in order. I put insert or delete in the question title because I assume it's easy to go between the two.

I have no idea how to start this. I have code for deleting rows when a observation is appended with "Total". However, how do I change it so it works for columns?

```
LR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cheese_D").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cheese")
    For i = LR To 2 Step -1
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cheese").Range("A" & i)
            If Right(.Value, 5) = "Total" Then .EntireRow.Delete
        End With
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: did u try `.EntireColumn.Delete`   ?

Comment: Right, `.EntireColumn.Delete`should delete the entire column. How can I change the other information in the For and With section to move across columns? 

I edited my code to show what LR was

Answer (score 0):

One way to look at columns in a range is like this:

```
Set rng = Range("L:S")
For Each col In rng.Columns
  'do your logic and .EntireColumn.Delete
next
```

---

Or look at all columns in sheet like this:

```
For Each col in ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cheese").Columns
  'your logic
Next
```

---

Now to add in your logic:

```
Set rng = Range("L:S")
For Each col In rng.Columns
  If Cells(1, col.Column).Value = "Total" Then col.EntireColumn.Delete
next
```

These four lines replace all your code in the original post.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting a type mismatch on the IF row

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it now.  Take a look.